# Bootstrap Datapicker - Use event onRender

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page, with a calendar bootstrap datapicker (Embedded / inline), i want introducing in each day of cell (td) , html code, for example, one list (`<ul><li>1</li></ul>`), I have to use, the event javascript `onRender()`, but i dont know like do it exactly?

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div id="datepicker" data-date="10/02/2015"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onRender: function (date) {
        //here i need, is to add a ul list to the table cell column (the cell with class "day")
        //return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
}).on("changeDate", function() {
    $("#my_hidden_input").val(
        $("#datepicker").datepicker('getFormattedDate')
    );
}).data('datepicker');
```

In a first moment, had added, this code, to the plugin:

```
html.push('<td class="'+clsName.join(' ')+'"' + (tooltip ? ' title="'+tooltip+'"' : '') + '>'
 + '<ul class="icons-calen"><li><img src="img/ico_calen_min_1.png" /></li><li><img src="img/ico_calen_min_2.png" /></li><li><img src="img/ico_calen_min_3.png" /></li><li><img src="img/ico_calen_min_4.png" /></li><li><img src="img/ico_calen_min_5.png" /></li></ul>'
 + '<ul class="numbers-calen"><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li></ul>'
 + '<ul class="day-calen"><li>' + prevMonth.getUTCDate() + '</li></ul>'
 + '</td>');
```

But, i know, that not is the best way, i need to the event onRender, How would be?

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker()
    .onRender(function (date) {
        alert("Insert html in cells table");
    })
    .on("changeDate", function() {
        $("#my_hidden_input").val(
            $("#datepicker").datepicker('getFormattedDate')
        );
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please show your code, hard just to imagine the setup and context :)

Comment: which datepicker library are you using?? As neither in jquery datepicker(`http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/`) nor in bootstrap datepicker(`https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html`) I can find the event onRender.

Comment: I base on this website: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: My calendar is based in bootstrap-datapicker inline / embedded